# How to mock stats method in elasticsearch?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, elasticsearch, mocha.js, sinon

I want to query stats of elasticsearch using nodeJs.

Here is my source code

```
const {Client}  = require('@elastic/elasticsearch');
client = new Client({
Connection:'appropriate aws connection',
node:'some url',
agent:{
  keepalive:,
  maxsocket:,
  maxfreesocket:
}
})

const stats = await client.nodes.stats();

console.log(stats);

// some operation on stats
```

How do i mock this elasticsearch method?
I have tried following but it is unable to mock the `stats()`.

```
 let sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
 before(()=>{
   sandbox.stub(Client.prototype,'nodes').get(()=>{
      stats: ()=>{
       return dymmydata;
     }
//where dummydata is already hardcoded
   })
 })
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: What do you mean you are unable to stub it? Is there any error?

Comment: Yes, call goes to actual function rather than stubbed function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see how the `nodes` API is defined. See [/v8.8.1/src/api/index.ts#L401](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js/blob/cd7f55ab9a080fadbf533cb9c733c0c3c6c98063/src/api/index.ts#L401), you will find the `nodes` API is defined by `Object.defineProperties` with a getter function.

```
Object.defineProperties(API.prototype, {
  // ...
  nodes: {
    get () { return this[kNodes] === null ? (this[kNodes] = new NodesApi(this.transport)) : this[kNodes] }
  }
  // ...
}
```

We should use `stub.get(getterFn)` API to replace a new getter for this stub.

E.g.

`index.js`:

```js
const { Client } = require('@elastic/elasticsearch');

const client = new Client({
    node: 'http://localhost:9200',
});

export function main() {
    return client.nodes.stats();
}
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
const sinon = require('sinon');
const { Client } = require('@elastic/elasticsearch');

describe('76653113', () => {
    it('should pass', async () => {
        const nodesApiMock = {
            stats: sinon.stub().resolves('ok'),
        };
        sinon.stub(Client.prototype, 'nodes').get(() => nodesApiMock);
        const { main } = require('./');
        const actual = await main();
        sinon.assert.match(actual, 'ok');
        sinon.assert.calledOnce(nodesApiMock.stats);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Lin Du, this works, but there is a problem while restoring the stub,
It says ```TypeError: Cannot delete property 'nodes' of #<Client>``` 
Do i have to follow any specific process to restore this?